# VBA code to find and replace offset value wont run

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues with the line beginning "fnd.offset"
Apparently the second part of the line doesn't have the object variable set? which creates a run time 91 error message when stepped through
I have this code placed within the 'RAG Data Input' sheet in the workbook (I intend to make it run after a button is pressed)

```
              Sub Replace_List()
    Dim Search As Range, cel As Range, n As Long
    Dim fnd As Range
    Dim fndFirst As String
    Dim wbToCheck As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Workbook
    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbToCheck = Workbooks("Test CP6 Y5 New Kent  Sussex Possession Minutes - New Version")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAG Data Input")
        Set Search = .Range("A5")
    End With

    For Each cel In Search
        Set fnd = 
       wbToCheck.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").find(What:=cel.Value, 
       LookAt:=xlWhole)
                fnd.Offset(0, 31).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAG Data 
 Input").Range("O1980").Value

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Replaced all items from the list.", vbInformation, "Replacements Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you tell us the actual error message, and show which line generates the error.

Comment: Run time error 91

Comment: Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Why don't you share what `"filename here"` exactly is? If you reference all objects (workbooks, worksheets, ranges) it will become much easier to pinpoint the issue. In your case, you either didn't set the workbook correctly or the worksheet "Planning Minutes" doesn't exist. Then there is the issue of `.Columns("B:B")` which should be either `.Columns("B")` or `.Range("B:B")`. Later on, you may have an issue with the unqualified `Worksheets("SHEET17")`.

Comment: Btw, you don't need a `For` loop if you're iterating over a single cell.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - I believe `Columns("B:B")` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @BigBen: You absolutely right. Amnesia!?

Comment: @AlessioFranzini says something ......  Set a DOT before the Range -----> Set rList = .Range("A5")

Comment: Hi all. I've updated the code and the question to highlight the next snag I'm running into. Thank you for the help provided so far

Answer (score 0):

When you are using "with" shouldn't the next line be:

`Set rList = .Range("A5")`

Otherwise the "with" is not needed. You should also write in your question on which line do you get the error

Comment: Hi there. I've updated the question to show which line causes the issue. the error is a run time 91 error which states the object variable or with block variable isnt set

Comment: Try adding the dot before Range("A5"), otherwise it will take that range from the current worksheet insetad of the "RAG Data Input" worksheet and given the fact that you use rList as a parameter to find "fnd" i think that might be the cause of your problem

Comment: could you provide what the updated code is supposed to do so? That would be helpful